# Need help understanding limit points

Tags: real-analysis

I am taking a course that is using Fitzpatrick's Advanced Calculus and we are currently discussing limit points. I know that there are more general topological ways of describing limit points but I would like to restrict our discussion to the following definition.

Definition: For a subset $D$ of the real numbers, the number $x_0$ is called a limit point of $D$ if there is a sequence in D\ {$x_0$} that converges to $x_0$.

My question is actually not directly from the textbook, but in my search to understand the topic I came across some lecture notes from another course at a different university, where the following example was given

1 and 3 are limit points of $D = (1,3)$ but 0.5 is not.

I understand why 1 and 3 are limit points, because you can find a sequence in (1,3) that converges to both points even though those points are not in the set.

But I don't understand why 0.5 is not called a limit point. Couldn't I find some sequence in  (1,3) that converges to 0.5 without actually reaching 0.5? I can't think of one off the top of my head though.

Comment: possible duplicate? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69033/help-me-understand-limits

Comment: That question has to do with limits yes but not this topic.

Comment: Suppose there is such a sequence $x_n\in (1,3) $ s.t., $x_n\to 1/2$. Pick any $0<\epsilon\le1/2$. By definition of convergence, there is sufficient large $N$ s.t., $d(x_n,1/2)<\epsilon$ whenever $n\ge N$. But this means $$0\le1/2-\epsilon<x_n<1/2+\epsilon\le1$$

i.e., $x_n\in (0,1)$, contradiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible to find a sequence $(x_n)_{n \geq 1}$ in $(1,3)$ that converges to $0.5$. Suppose there is one such sequence. Then, given $\epsilon = 0.25 $, exists $n_0 \in \Bbb N$ such that $n > n_0$ implies $|x_n - 0.5| < 0.25$, that is, $0.25 < x_n < 0.75$, and so $x_n \not\in (1,3)$. Intuitively, $0.5$ is too far from $(1,3)$. You want the *whole* sequence to be in the set $D$.

Comment: I just realized I made a really silly mistake. For some dumb reason I kept thinking that 0.5 was in the interval (1,3)! Of course I can see now that there is no way that you can get a sequence to converge to 0.5 that is completely obtained in (1,3). On a related note, does that mean that any value in the interval (1,3) can be considered a limit point of (1,3)?

Comment: Yes! Take $x \in (1,3)$ and make: $$x_n = 1 + \frac{n}{n+1}(x-1). $$ You can check as an (good) exercise that $x_n \in (1,3)$, for all $n$, and that $x_n \to x $ :)

Comment: Thinking of geometry, I "parametrized" the segment $(1,x)$..

Comment: You could also define $x_n = x$ and then clearly $x_n \rightarrow x$ :D

Comment: The definition asks for a sequence in $D \setminus \{x_0\}$. That's why I didn't used a constant sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could if you had things near $0.5$, but the smallest number you can achieve using a sequence is $1$, using the definition of convergence of a sequence, and taking $\varepsilon = 0.25$ you can clearly see there is no value in $(1,3)$ wich is at that distance from $0.5$.